# ggsave how to not overwrite?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there an option to not overwrite existing files? Maybe it can automatically save them as: `file_name.png`, `file_name (2).png`, `file_name (3).png`, as how Windows deal with same-name files.

Sample code:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat = data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)
for (i in 1:3){
        p1 = ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
                geom_point()
        ggsave('p1.png', p1, width = 10, height = 8, dpi = 72,
               overwrite = F)
}
```

Comment: Use `paste` to create unique name.

Answer (score 4):

Use `paste` function to create unique name based on `i`, i.e.:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat = data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)
for (i in 1:3){
  p1 = ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
         geom_point()
  ggsave(paste0("p",i,".png"), p1, width = 10, height = 8, dpi = 72)
}
```

From Roland's comment:

```
ggsave(sprintf("p%d.png", i), p1, width = 10, height = 8, dpi = 72)
```

Comment: Or `sprintf("p%d.png", i)`.